# Struts 2 s:optgroup elements are not pre-selected

Tags: jsp, struts2

Problem: When using a select (`s:select`) element that supports multiple selection (`multiple="true"`) with option groups (`s:optgroup`), if the field has values corresponding to elements of the option group elements, they will not default to selected.

Similar configurations that do work as expected:

- When the `list`s in the `s:optgroup` are instead provided as the list for the `s:select` element, the correct options will default to selected.
- If the same, or different, lists is are to both `s:select` and `s:optgroup`, the elements in `s:select` will be correctly selected, but those in `s:optgroup` will not.
- When the `s:select` element instead supports only single selection (no `multiple="true"`), and the field (mySelections) is changed to an Integer instead of a List, the correct options will default to selected.

In all cases (both the problem case and the similar cases that work as expected), the selected elements are being correctly submitted to the action, as one would expect given it is just HTML at that point.

JSP that is causing the problem:

```
<s:select
    name="mySelections"
    list="#{9:'Z'}"
    multiple="true"
    size="5">
    <s:optgroup
        label="List A"
        list="#{1:'A',2:'B',3:'C'}" />
    <s:optgroup
        label="List B"
        list="#{4:'D',5:'E'}" />
</s:select>
```

On the off chance it was related to the UI theme, I tried against both "simple" (the one I actually use), and the default ("xhtml"), but the issue presents in both.

There is an [open JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/WW-4367) that looks related, in that the user's example does specify a multiple-select field, though the user does not identify if single-select works.

If this is a known issue, which the JIRA issue would suggest, does there exist a known workaround? However, it seems like this is something that would have been noted more frequently, if it were an issue with Struts2, and thus I am suspecting it is my error rather than the framework's that is causing the issue.

Differences between my actual case and the example above: In my actual case the `list`s are properties on the action, instead of static, and `s:select` list has no elements (`{}`).

The version of Struts 2 is 2.3.16.2.

---

My expectation is that the suggested workaround would be to just generate the `select` tag and its descendants using JSP. If so, are there any "gotchas" with regards to using a non-Struts tag in my interface?

Comment: Looks like a tiny bug in `<s:optgroup>` tag. I opened a jira issue for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4387. Not sure if WW-4367 is related or not.